# can not parse getElementById

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function which produces the correct value when run, but I am having a hell of a time displaying the results.

Here is the JS which is calculated onChange in a form I am trying to display the resulting value elsewhere on the form. The `alert` displays the correct value but my `id` remains blank.

Thanks in advance for taking a look

```
function calculate_mtow1() {
    togw_n = 0;
    togw = $('#togw').val();

    if (togw != '' && togw != 0 && togw != 'Nan') {
        var togw = togw.replace(",", "");
        togw_n = togw;
    }

    burn_n = 0;
    burn = $('#burn').val();
    if (burn != '' && burn !=0 && burn != 'Nan') {
        var burn = burn.replace(",", "");
        burn_n = burn;
    }

    var mtow1 = parseInt(togw_n) + parseInt(burn_n);
    $('#mtow1').val(mtow1);
    document.getElementById('mtow1');
    alert(mtow1);
}
```

```html
<td>TOW + Fuel Burn =<span id="mtow1"></span></td>
```

Comment: What have you done to debug your code? Did you check whether the variables have the values you expect? If they have not, what exactly is different from what you expect? The title of your question makes little sense to me. `getElementById` is a *method*. I don't understand why you mean by "parsing" a method. You have to do a bit more work up front, you cannot just post your code here and say "something is not working like I want it to".

Comment: Firstly, you have an odd mix of native JS and jQuery. Secondly, what are you trying to do with this code? Your penultimate line uses `getElementById()`, but doesn't assign the returned DOMElement to anything? You're also redefining the scope of implicitly declared variables by using `var` statements within `if` conditions. You need to check using the `isNaN()` function, not against a `'Nan` string. Finally, `span` elements do not have a value to set, so you should use `text()` or `html()`.

Comment: Is the `$('#mtow1')` pointing to a form element (input, select, textarea)? If not, that should use `html` not `val`.

Comment: As you are using .val() on a span, it won't work, as .val() works just for input DOM Elements. You would need to use .text() instead.

Comment: "A hell of a time" does not really qualify as a problem description. It does not really tell us anything about what happens.

Comment: Guys sorry, ( I did not write the code snippet)  I am not a coder I am just trying to help a friend get this working for his website. The frustrating part is when I run the form the alert displays a message with the correct value. I am just having trouble displaying the value of mtow1 in the span. Thanks for the help Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is getting the element with `getElementById` but then not doing anything with it. You need to assign the result of `getElementById` to something, or call methods on it on the same line. If your goal is to put the value of `mtow1` into your `<span>`, try doing this:

```
// Solution 1
var spanElement = document.getElementById("mtow1");
spanElement.innerHtml = mtow1;
```

Alternatively, perhaps you were trying to display the value of `mtow1` by using this jQuery:

```
$('#mtow1').val(mtow1);
```

That doesn't do what you think it does. It changes the "value" attribute of the span to the value of mtow1, but that change isn't visible to the user. It's the same as writing this as your HTML:

```
<td>TOW + Fuel Burn =<span id="mtow1" value="valueofmtow1"></span></td>
```

If you want to use jQuery instead of the `getElementById` method I posted above, you could do this:

```
// Solution 2
$('#mtow1').html(mtow1);
```

You don't need to do both. Either solution will work on its own.

Comment: Joshua Thank you for your answer I am in fact just trying to display the value of "mtow1" in a form. the users enter data and the onChange calculates the value.  I have changed the function to use your solution 2 but still the value is not shown in the span.

Comment: Jushua Thank you I was alble to get this working.